# Successive ajax requests are not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been working on successive AJAX calls. what I want from my system is, to first execute first call and on success of it, print all the messages with specified time delay and once all messages of response get printed, call other method for next AJAX request and so on. Below is my code for AJAX handler:

```
 function addNewFootballCat(action) {

                        if($("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == "" || $("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == 0 || $("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == null) {
                            alert("Please select category");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            var selected_cat_id = $("#categories_id_dropdown").val();
                            $("#waitingcategoryinsert").css('display','block');
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'fun.php',
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: "html",
                                async : false,
                                data: "cat_id="+selected_cat_id+"&action="+action ,                                    
                                success: function(jsondata){
                                    var data = $.trim(jsondata);
                                    var data_array = data.split(',');                                        
                                    var created_cat_msg_array = [];
                                    $.each( data_array, function( key, value ) {                                        
                                    if (value.indexOf('already_exist') > -1) {
                                        v = value.replace('already_exist', '');
                                        var map = confirm('Do you really want to map '+v+' with '+v+' category?');
                                        if(map == true){
                                            alert('mapped');
                                        }else{
                                            alert('not mapped');
                                        }
                                        } else {
                                            created_cat_msg_array.push(value);                                                                            
                                        }
                                    });
                                    i = 0;
                                     interval = setInterval(function(){
                                        if(i > created_cat_msg_array.length)
                                            clearInterval(interval);
                                        $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").html(created_cat_msg_array[i++]);
                                    }, 1000);  
                                },
                                complete: function() {
                                    //for Kid categories-products
                                    addNewKidCat('create_kid_sub_category');
                                }
                            });
                        } 
                    }

                    function addNewKidCat(action) {
                        if($("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == "" || $("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == 0 || $("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == null) {
                            alert("Please select category");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            var selected_cat_id = $("#categories_id_dropdown").val();
                            $("#waitingcategoryinsert").css('display','block');
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'fun.php',
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: "html",
                                async : false,
                                data: "cat_id="+selected_cat_id+"&action="+action ,                                    
                                success: function(jsondata){
                                    var data = $.trim(jsondata);
                                    var data_array = data.split(',');                                        
                                    var created_cat_msg_array = [];
                                    $.each( data_array, function( key, value ) {                                        
                                    if (value.indexOf('already_exist') > -1) {
                                        v = value.replace('already_exist', '');
                                        var map = confirm('Do you really want to map '+v+' with '+v+' category?');
                                        if(map == true){
                                            alert('mapped');
                                        }else{
                                            alert('not mapped');
                                        }
                                        } else {
                                            created_cat_msg_array.push(value);                                                                            
                                        }
                                    });
                                    i = 0;
                                     interval = setInterval(function(){
                                        if(i > created_cat_msg_array.length)
                                            clearInterval(interval);
                                        $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").html(created_cat_msg_array[i++]);
                                    }, 1000);                          
                                   },
                                complete: function() {
                                    //for training kit categories-products
                                    addNewTrainingCat('create_training_sub_categories');
                                }                                 
                            });
                        } 
                    }
                    function addNewTrainingCat(action) {
                        if($("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == "" || $("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == 0 || $("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == null) {
                            alert("Please select category");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            var selected_cat_id = $("#categories_id_dropdown").val();
                            $("#waitingcategoryinsert").css('display','block');
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'fun.php',
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: "html",
                                async : false,
                                data: "cat_id="+selected_cat_id+"&action="+action ,                                    
                                success: function(jsondata){
                                    var data = $.trim(jsondata);
                                    var data_array = data.split(',');                                        
                                    var created_cat_msg_array = [];
                                    $.each( data_array, function( key, value ) {                                        
                                    if (value.indexOf('already_exist') > -1) {
                                        v = value.replace('already_exist', '');
                                        var map = confirm('Do you really want to map '+v+' with '+v+' category?');
                                        if(map == true){
                                            alert('mapped');
                                        }else{
                                            alert('not mapped');
                                        }
                                        } else {
                                            created_cat_msg_array.push(value);                                                                            
                                        }
                                    });
                                    i = 0;
                                     interval = setInterval(function(){
                                        if(i > created_cat_msg_array.length)
                                            clearInterval(interval);
                                        $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").html(created_cat_msg_array[i++]);
                                    }, 1000);                     
                                   },
                                   complete: function() {
                                    //for training kit categories-products
                                    addNewAccessoriesCat('create_accessories_sub_categories');
                                }                                 
                            });
                        } 
                    }
                    function addNewAccessoriesCat(action) {
                        if($("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == "" || $("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == 0 || $("#categories_id_dropdown").val() == null) {
                            alert("Please select category");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            var selected_cat_id = $("#categories_id_dropdown").val();
                            $("#waitingcategoryinsert").css('display','block');
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'fun.php',
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: "html",
                                async : false,
                                data: "cat_id="+selected_cat_id+"&action="+action ,                                    
                                success: function(jsondata){
                                    var data = $.trim(jsondata);
                                    var data_array = data.split(',');                                        
                                    var created_cat_msg_array = [];
                                    $.each( data_array, function( key, value ) {                                        
                                    if (value.indexOf('already_exist') > -1) {
                                        v = value.replace('already_exist', '');
                                        var map = confirm('Do you really want to map '+v+' with '+v+' category?');
                                        if(map == true){
                                            alert('mapped');
                                        }else{
                                            alert('not mapped');
                                        }
                                        } else {
                                            created_cat_msg_array.push(value);                                                                            
                                        }
                                    });
                                    i = 0;
                                     interval = setInterval(function(){
                                        if(i > created_cat_msg_array.length)
                                            clearInterval(interval);
                                        $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").html(created_cat_msg_array[i++]);
                                    }, 1000);
                                   }                                  
                            });
                        } 
                    }
```

and below is PHP code:

```
if ($action == 'create_football_sub_categories') {
echo 'first pessage,';
echo 'first pessage1';
}

if ($action == 'create_kid_sub_category') {
 echo 'second passage,';
 echo 'second passage1';
}
if ($action == 'create_training_sub_categories') {
 echo 'third passage,';
 echo 'third passage1';
 }
 if ($action == 'create_accessories_sub_categories') {
  echo 'fourth passage,';
  echo 'fourth passage1';
  }
```

Now the issue is, it is performing all actions correctly but it doesn't print all the messages and I really don't know the reason behind. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably look into https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is an asynchron request, means that some of your request will have more delay than others.

Comment: True, but what if some of them are not at all executing. when I run this code, it prints only "first pessage" and "second pessage1". Why other messages not get printed?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The problem is in interval functionality. I have replaced it with :

```
$.each(created_cat_msg_array, function(key,value) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     $("#waitingcategoryinsert span").html(value);
     },2000 + ( i * 2000 ));
     i=i+1;
});
```